# Process Builder Setup does not load Apex class list

Tags: apex, process-builder, invocable-method

On my sandbox org this request failed when I try to select Apex as an action in Setup > Process Builder:

[/aura?r=8&ui-process-builder-components-controller-common.ApexTypesDataProvider.getApexClassList=1](http:///aura?r=8&ui-process-builder-components-controller-common.ApexTypesDataProvider.getApexClassList=1)

And i see error:

> Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem
>   continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID
>   shown here and any other related details. Error ID: 24769416-25943
>   (317755707)

But in Flows I can use apex classes as actions (it does request to [/aura?r=6&ui-interaction-builder-components-controllers.FlowBuilder.getAllInvocableActionsForType=1](http:///aura?r=6&ui-interaction-builder-components-controllers.FlowBuilder.getAllInvocableActionsForType=1) and it works)

Comment: For invoking apex in process builder the method needs to be invocableMethod.

Comment: I know, and it works fine on other dev orgs, but does not work on my sandbox org

Comment: 1) close Process in PB
2) Go to Setup / Develop / Apex Classes and click "Compile all classes"
3) Try to go to your process and select your class

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately

Comment: It's more likely that it's something Salesforce support will have to look into where you can provide the error ID. Is it a partial sandbox or just a dev org?

Comment: It is sandbox org. Do you know to contact support with this question?

Comment: If you click on the question mark and select "Help" you should get routed to their support website where you can create a case or follow their directions [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workcom_contact_support.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 1):

That error message is part of a "gack". Gacks are salesforce internal errors that you can't usually fix on your own. Think of them as an unhandled salesforce error.

Theres a lot of resources out there about gacks but at the end of the day they all say the same thing - only salesforce knows what this error means and only salesforce can fix it.

[What is a Gack?](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html)

> What you are looking at is what we call a GACK. A gack is our blue screen of death, our frowny Mac icon, our “the number you have reached is no longer in service”, our “Jedediah has died of dysentery”. A gack is what happens when an error got thrown within our application and we didn’t catch it and handle it.
>
> What this means is that it’s not your fault. It’s ours. That’s why we apologize in that message. Sorry!
>
> This friendly message is the above-water portion of a huge iceberg of functionality. The numbers you see are part of an elaborate system for efficiently bringing these events to the attention of R&D. This post will help you understand that system, and how you can help us in getting you running safely. (Hint: steer away from icebergs.)

This blog post goes into detail about some aspects of the gack and how to report it. It offers great advice, expect for posting on stack exchange -  we really can't help you fix this exception. Sometimes, maybe, if its caused by code you wrote but not something baked into the standard functionality of salesforce.

Comment: So which portion in error message is giveaway that it's a gack. Based on your experience is there any pattern in error message to look for. Thanks.

Comment: Its this bit of the message `24769416-25943 (317755707)` . The `###-## (##)` is a dead giveaway.